# Error con evento que se repite siempre que hago scroll

Tags: javascript

he desarrollado con mucho sudor un mini proceso "countdown" que se activa solo cuando el objeto esta visible en la pantalla. El problema que este se repite a partir de ahí siempre que hago scroll con el ratón y **solo debería pasar una vez**

Os dejo el codigo JS por aqui:

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', function (event) {
var element = document.querySelector('#main-container');
var position = element.getBoundingClientRect();
if (position.top < window.innerHeight) {
    var timeleft = 75;
    var downloadTimer = setInterval(function () {
        if (timeleft <= 0) {
            clearInterval(downloadTimer);
            document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = "0,-";
        } else {
            document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = timeleft + ",-";
        }
        timeleft -= 1;
    }, 20);
}
```

});

Si alguno me pudiese ayudar, se lo agradecería muchísimo.
Un saludo

Comment: Podrías añadirle a `#main-container` una clase cuando hayas ejecutado tu función. Luego, en el `if` que tienes preguntas si `#main-container` tiene dicha clase y así en caso de tenerla evitas que se vuelva a ejecutar lo que no quieres que haga de nuevo.

Answer (score 0):

Los eventos se pueden añadir y también se pueden eliminar. Los añades con elemento.addEventListener(evento, handler) y los eliminasa con elemento.removeEventListener(evento, handler).
Si quiers que el evento solo se ejecute UNA vez pues lo desactivas en la función que se dispara la primera vez que ocurre.

```
eScroll= function (event) {
window.removeEventListener('scroll',eScroll);
var element = document.querySelector('#main-container');
var position = element.getBoundingClientRect();
if (position.top < window.innerHeight) {
    var timeleft = 75;
    var downloadTimer = setInterval(function () {
        if (timeleft <= 0) {
            clearInterval(downloadTimer);
            document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = "0,-";
        } else {
            document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = timeleft + ",-";
        }
        timeleft -= 1;
        }, 20);
    }
}
window.addEventListener('scroll',eScroll);
```